# error undefined index en formulario php

Tags: php, html

Tengo un formulario con los siguientes campos:

```
<form action="estefichero.php" method="POST">
     <input type="checkbox" id="descripcion" name="subcheck[]"></input><br>

    obervaciones <input type="textarea" name="text[]" id="observaciones" />

    <input type="submit" name="guardar" />


 if(isset($_POST['guardar'])){

print_r($_REQUEST['observacion']);
print_r($_REQUEST['descripcion']);

}
```

El problema es que cada vez que le doy a el input type SUBMIT(boton),me salta el error undefined index:observacion y undefined index:descripcion,

dónde está el fallo?

Comment: Las claves que debes buscar en `$_REQUEST` son las correspondientes a `name` en el formulario, no a `id`. Debería ser `$_REQUEST['subcheck']`y `$_REQUEST['text']` En vez de `$_REQUEST` puedes usar `$_POST` directamente....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando envías un formulario, este se serializado en un array cuyas claves son las etiquetas `name` de cada elemento, y los valores son el valor que tenga cada elemento.

Esto lamentablemente no queda muy claro en el Manual de PHP, pero aparece en [una nota de los colaboradores](http://php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.post.php#119608).

Por tanto, para tu caso debes buscar la información usando las claves `subcheck` y `text`. Fíjate que en el caso del botón sí lo estabas haciendo bien, pues el mismo tiene como name la palabra `guardar`.

Y, por cierto, debes cerrar tu formulario:

#### HTML

```
<form action="estefichero.php" method="POST">
     <input type="checkbox" id="descripcion" name="subcheck[]" /><br>
    obervaciones <input type="textarea" name="text[]" id="observaciones" />
    <input type="submit" name="guardar" />
</form>
```

#### PHP

```
if(isset($_POST['guardar'])){
    print_r($_POST['subcheck']);
    print_r($_POST['text']);
}
```